# Theme changing in angular with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have an angular application where I am providing users with theme selection settings (Below is the image.). Whenever the user switches themes, I change my theme using JQUERY. Below is the function.

```
    changeTheme(themeColor: string) {
if (themeColor) {
  let navbarElement = document.querySelector('.navbar');
  let sidebarElement = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  navbarElement.setAttribute('data-background-color', themeColor);
  sidebarElement.setAttribute('data-background-color', themeColor);
  localStorage.setItem('userThemePreference', themeColor);
}}
```

I just set the attribute of the HTML element which I have defined in the SASS files. It looks like this if the blue colour is selected. Similar functions for other colours as well.

```
  &[data-background-color="blue"] {
    @include sidebar-background-color($new-blue, $azure-color-bottom, $white-color);
    @include set-background-color-button($white-color);
    @include sidebar-active-color($black-color);

    .user,
    .logo,
    .nav li.separator {
      &:after {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      }
    }

    .nav {
      li:hover:not(.active) > a,
      li.active > [data-toggle="collapse"] {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      }
    }
  }
```

The above function comes under the element structure mentioned below: Inside the sidebar class, all the styles will be applied.

```
<element class="sidebar" data-background-color="blue">
  …
    <element class="nav">
      …
        <li class="separator">
```

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmAqo.png), you can see a red coloured button. That comes under the card class and in the card-header class. I want to change the colour of that button as well according to the theme. I have written a mixin and I tried to include that mixin in the theme settings. But it doesn't work. Here is the mixin I have written. I tried with just .card and just .card-header and both.

```
@mixin set-card-header-linear-gradient($color) {
  .main-content > .row > .col-md-12 > .card > .card-header {
    @include icon-gradient($new-blue, $azure-color-bottom);

  }
}
```

**My question is, if I include this mixin (@include set-card-header-linear-gradient($white);) in my theme setting, Should the button come under the sidebar class only since the theme setting is under sidebar structure as mentioned above ? How to do these settings so that all the button's colors across my entire application will be changed ?**

[image]